# Why doesn't ${@:-1} return the last element of $@?

Tags: bash

*I thought to post up a Q&A on this as I did not find anything similar. If it already exists, please mark this as a duplicate.*

---

The following code, running under Bash shell, doesn't work (should return just `f`, the last (-1-th) item in `$@`):

```
$ set -- a b c d e f
$ echo ${@:-1}
a b c d e f
```

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate on U&L though...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### `${parameter:-word}` is a type of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **`${parameter:-word}`**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
>   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

---

So `${@:-1}` is interpreted as:

- If `$@` is unset or null, substitute with `1`
- Else leave `$@` as it is

Since the latter is true, `echo` prints `$@` in all its glory

---

#### The Fix:

Put some space between `:` and `-`:

```
$ echo ${@: -1}
f
```

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative syntax to the space suggested by Zaid, you can also use round brackets to get the functionality you want:

```
echo ${@:(-1)}
```

> f

Comment: ++; lest people think that the `(…)` creates an expensive _subshell_ (as I originally did): it doesn't, because array subscript ranges are evaluated in an _arithmetic_ context  (implied `$(( … ))`), so using `(…)` comes with _no_ performance penalty (to speak of).

Answer (score 0):

#### Some explanations

Have a look under section ***Parameter Expansion*** in the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s man page:

> - `${parameter:-word}` -> **Use  Default  Values.** If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted...
> - `${parameter:=word}` -> ***Assign Default Values.*** If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter...
> - `${parameter:?word}` -> ***Display Error if Null or Unset.***  If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word is written to the standard error and the shell, ...
> - ...

Well, the syntax `${@:-1}` will return `1` if `$@` is empty...

```
echo ${@:-1}
a b c d e f

set --
echo ${@:-1}
1

echo ${@:-It is.}
It is.
```

Working around could be done with anything that break `:-` syntax.

```
set -- alpha beta ceta delta enigma foo
echo ${@: -1} 
foo
echo ${@:0-1}
foo
echo ${@:(-1)}
foo
echo ${@:10#-1}
foo
echo ${@:1*-1}
foo
```

#### All arrays are affected in same manner.

```
array=(Hello good world)

echo ${array[@]:-1}
Hello good world

echo ${array[@]:0-1}
world
```